# Cassandra: how to search key columns with DECIMAL?

Tags: select, search, cassandra, int, decimal

I understand Cassandra is designed for String based Key/Value pair.
I have a need to have Cassandra table with Decimal keys. Is there anyway to search the keys with range of numeric values. Like keys between 3 and 6 (inclusive)??.

### Sample Key Column

1

3.3

6.345

9

10

2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this out.  Assume a simple table with a `decimal` key, and a `text` value.

```
CREATE TABLE decimalRangePK (dec decimal, value text, PRIMARY KEY (dec));
```

In this case, `dec` is my partition key.  And it is my only key, as there is not a clustering key present.  After INSERTing some data, here is what I have:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM decimalrangepk ;

 dec  | value
------+-------
  2.5 |   ghi
 6.35 |   abc
    9 |   def
  3.2 |   3.2
    1 |     1
  3.3 |   3.3
   10 |   ten

(7 rows)
```

So I assume that you are trying a range query on your partition key, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM decimalrangeck WHERE dec>=3.3 AND dec<=9;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

As you can see, this doesn't work.  Cassandra cannot execute range query on a partition key.  However, because clustering keys are used enforce on-disk sort order (within a partition key) you *can* execute a range query on a clustering key.

In this next example, I'll try this again.  But this time I will partition my data by date, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE decimalRangeCK (dateBucket text, dec decimal, value text,
     PRIMARY KEY (dateBucket,dec));
```

After inserting some rows, I'll query the table and it will look slightly different:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM decimalrangeck ;

 datebucket | dec  | value
------------+------+-------
   20151108 |    1 |     1
   20151108 |  3.2 |   3.2
   20151110 |  2.5 |   ghi
   20151110 |   10 |   ten
   20151109 |    1 |     1
   20151109 |  3.3 |   3.3
   20151109 | 6.35 |   abc
   20151109 |    9 |   def

(8 rows)
```

Now I can run a range query on `dec`, ***as long as I also provide a partition key***:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM decimalrangeck WHERE datebucket='20151109'
                             AND dec>=3.3 AND dec<=9;

 datebucket | dec  | value
------------+------+-------
   20151109 |  3.3 |   3.3
   20151109 | 6.35 |   abc
   20151109 |    9 |   def

(3 rows)
```

As you can see, picking a good partition key is very important.  High cardinality, unique partition keys are great for data distribution, but don't really give you a whole lot of query flexibility.